# Sorting Yahoo Pipes entry by last word via RegEx

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I'm trying to sort items generated by Yahoo Pipes from a CSV file by the last word of one of the entries of the generated items:

Example JSON item generated by [this Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=5f6972eb6c93cd86b1380d012b16419d):

```
"items": [
  {
    "name": "Prof. Dr.-Ing. Richard Bamler",
    "link": "http:\/\/www.lmf.bv.tum.de",
    "lehrstuhl": "Lehrstuhl f\u00fcr Methodik der Fernerkundung",
    "y:row": "1",
    "description": null,
    "title": null
  },
```

I guess I need a RegEx to extract the last word of the name string (1st problem), which I can't quite figure out.

As always, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I reworked your pipe a little bit](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=d0a889244a548cd417a983e3ff304b80). I'm not familiar with localized titles, but it appears that "komm." is a suffix rather than a name, so I built an exception into the end of the regex for that.

The rule should look like:

replace `^.* ([^ \.]+)( komm\.)?$` with `$1`

---

The `$1` is a backreference to the first matched group `([^ \.]+)`. The matching group matches the last continuous set of characters that are not a space or period.

This form was necessary because the regex will run in a Javascript environment, and Javascript does not handle non-ascii characters like `ü` properly (it considers it a non-word).

It also has the `( komm\.)?` at the end so that it can ignore that suffix, if present.

Beyond that, I made a couple of changes to clean up the output so it's a little more legible.

Comment: Sweet, that's exactly what I was trying to achieve. 

You're right about the komm., it's a localized title (meaning temporary). 

Thanks a lot for fixing the pipe and showing me how RegEx are applied, I'm going to look into them a lot more now.

Thank you!

Comment: Always happy to help! ^_^ A good place to start looking into RegExes is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions